# Forcing column height and scroll

Tags: html, css

Consider two columns `nav` and `menu`. I want the height of `menu` to be always equal to `nav`.

If Height(`menu`) > Height(`nav`), `menu` contents should be scrollable.

If Height(`menu`) < Height(`nav`), `menu` (or its `background-color`) should still match the height of `nav`.

EDIT:
The height of `menu` can vary. The contents/items in `nav` are fixed. So, in theory it is possible to add up all the element heights and line heights in advance and fix its height.

1) Is a solution possible, if `nav` height is unknown ?

2) If (1) is not possible, is it a good idea to add up the line heights/element heights to pre-determine `nav`'s height ?

I have been struggling with this. I've read up on the solutions ([link1](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/), [link2](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks), [link3](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/)) to the problem of equal column heights - but it is not the same. There is no scrolling involved in those cases.

Thanks for your help.

```css
html, body, nav, menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
}
menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #C5CAE9;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav></nav>
    <menu></menu>
</div>
```

Comment: If the height of nav is known, and the height of menu will always equal the height of nav, can you not just set the height of menu to that value? Its contents may still have a greater height, giving you the scroll where appropriate.

Comment: ah! yes ... I was struggling with the case where `nav` is unknown. The only way I can know `nav` is by adding up all the `nav` items' line heights, element heights ... and then setting that as its height -- something that is painful.